# Is it possible to repeat a loop after trying a limited amount of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm new to programming and I'm struggling a lot to define a "try again" after a set amount of times on my little guessing game. This is the code that I'm using:

```
import random

t = 0
max_tries = 3
answer = random.randint(0,10)
yes_choice = ['yes', 'y', 'yep']
no_choice = ['no', 'n', 'nope']


while t < max_tries:

    t += 1
    print('GUESS A NUMBER 0-10')
    num = int(input('Choose Thy Number?:'))

    if num < answer:
        print('Higher!')

    elif num > answer:
        print('Lower!')

    elif num == answer:
        t -= 3
        print(f'Congratulations human, your number was {answer: ,}!')
        cont = input('Do you wish to continue playing? (y/n)').lower()
        if cont in yes_choice:
            print('As you wish!')
            continue

        elif cont in no_choice:
            print('Coward!')
            break

    else:
        t -= 3

        print(f'Mistakes Everywhere! Your answer was {answer: ,}!')
        cont = input('Do you wish to continue playing? (y/n)').lower()
        if cont in yes_choice:
                print('As you wish!')
                continue

        elif cont in no_choice:
            print('Coward!')
            break
```

It is not reading the "else" inside the while loop, and when the condition turns to "False", it just "breaks" the program and exits.
Hope that you can help me, thank you for your time.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: There is no possible route where the else condition will be activated. All conditions are used in the `if` and `elif` condition statements.

Comment: My statement above only applies to the conditions that are on the indentation level of `else` right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things I'd like to point out. They won't fix anything though.

- Instead of subtracting 3 of `t`, set `t=0` instead. `t-=3` might cause `t` to go to negatives (unless this was on purpose)
- The while loop will stop as soon as `t` exceeds `max_tries`. This means that it might not "retry" every time. `while True:` or `while bool` will fix it. (`bool` can be a variable of boolean type).
- You don't specify `num` after you guess correctly and play again. Just put `num = random.randint(1,10)` right before `continue`.

Now, back to your original question:

Your else statement will never be reached. This is because all the conditions (`num < answer`, `num > answer`, and `num == answer`) are all specified. There is no other possible operation between `num` and `answer` that you can do, hence `else` will never be reached.

To fix this, you can use an `if` statement *before the first current if*.

```py
if t < max_tries:
    t -= 3
    print(f'Mistakes Everywhere! Your answer was {answer: ,}!')
    cont = input('Do you wish to continue playing? (y/n)').lower()
    if cont in yes_choice:
        print('As you wish!')
        continue

    elif cont in no_choice:
        print('Coward!')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It help me a lot. I was able to solve my problems with your points